# jquery show data taken by select after removing parenthesis

Tags: jquery, html

I have an `html` `select` and a `div` where I want to show a message depending on the select option. The `<select id='select1'>` shows options like `"Player1(Mike)"` and I want only the `"Player1"` to show up in the `<div id='logId1'></div>`. 
I wrote the following code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#select1").on("change", function() {
            $("#logId1").html($(this).find(":selected").text(function(_, text) {
                return text.replace(/\(.*?\)/g, "");
            }));

        });
});
</script>
```

It shows what I want but the result `"Player1"` shows up like it is selected.
I'm a newbie in jquery so any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are modifying the text of selected option, when you use `.text(fn)` method.

You need to get the `.text()` and then perform the desired operation.

```
$("#select1").on("change", function() {        
    $("#logId1").html($(this).find(":selected").text().replace(/\(.*?\)/g, ""));
});
```

Comment: oh god I tried the text but without () so it didn't work. Thank you for the fast answer!